# Limits- when is this substitution allowed?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Suppose that you are calculating the limit, as $x$ approaches some real number, or plus/minus infinity, of an expression containing $f(x)$; $\sqrt {f(x)+x^2}$, for istance. If you find a function $g(x)$ such that $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ approaches $1$ when $x$ approaches the same real number (which, I think, should be written like this $f(x)\sim g(x)$), when are you allowed to substitute $g(x)$ to $f(x)$ in the original limit?

For example, I've found on the Internet a proof that if

1. $f_1(x)\sim f_2(x)$
2. $g_1(x)\sim g_2(x)$
3. $h_1(x)\sim h_2(x)$

for $x\rightarrow c$, then $$\lim_{x\rightarrow c}{\frac{f_1(x)g_1(x)}{h_1(x)}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow c}{\frac{f_2(x)g_2(x)}{h_2(x)}}$$
 but I'm interested to know if there are other cases in which this kind of substitution is allowed.

Comment: You can always substitute if multiplication and division are the only operations involved. If something else is involved - addition, exponentiation, … - you generally can't substitute.